# highchatrs arabic translation is not working perfectly

Tags: highcharts, translation, arabic, chartkick

I'm trying to translate a graphs language from English to Arabic, I'm using ruby on rails with haml, I also have chartkick gem, and highcharts, here is what I did: 
on the view i have a div with an Id 'con'

```
#con
```

and for the JavaScript I have this:

```
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'con'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'أضغط لعرضها فى المقدمة'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
    }]
});
```

my problem is when I run this on Firefox everything works perfectly 
and it gives me the correct title

> أضغط لعرضها فى المقدمة

but when I run it on chrome it gives me the reversed latter and they are not connected to each others something like this:

> ف ي ةم د ق م ل ا.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this, just in case someone else needed the answer: you should add `useHTML: true`

```
 var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
    renderTo: 'con'
},

title: {
    text: 'أضغط لعرضها فى المقدمة',
    useHTML: true
},
.....
```